# Editing contents of an Android xml resource file in java

Tags: java, android

I currently have an xml file under my res/value and I wish to add items/edit the file. 
I am able to obtain information from the file using this

```
String[] listItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listitems);
```

but I can't find a way to edit it.
The xml file is called strings with an array inside called `listitems`.

Comment: You need to tag this question as "android" or else the android people will not be able to find it and help you

Answer (score 1):

In Android development, the res/value xml is intended to static, meaning it should not, and cannot be edited by the application at runtime.

If your list needs to be dynamic, and needs to be stored on the user's device, then you need to find another method of storing the data. See this link for info on data storage in android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html